# AVR reading from LCD hd44780

Tags: serial-port, avr, usart, hd44780

I am currently writing a small project based on avr ATmega32 and a few other components (LED, microswitch).
I am using Mirosław Kardaś's LCD library and header file from ftp://novitech.pl/Ladowarka/LCD/ .
Also I use this function to send data via RS232:

```
char USART_wysylanie ()
{
    while ( !(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)) );
    UDR = data;
}
```

The task I made for myself is to get via rs232 the data that is currently displayed on my hd44780 2x16 (connected via 4bit). The thing is that when I use

```
        if (KEY_DOWN_3)
    {
        unsigned char message;
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<=4;i++)
        {
           lcd_locate(0,i);
           message = _lcd_read_byte();
           USART_wysylanie(message);
        }
    }
```

my terminal shows nothing when set to ANSII, when displaying as HEX I get 01 02 03... and all over again, bt I want to get exactly what is on my LCD, and in it's RAM. The communication with RS is good because when I use something like `... USART_wysylanie ('s')` everything is OK. Any ideas how can I make my code to READ LCD content?

Comment: What is your F_CPU ... there are no delays or `check_BF` in `_lcd_read_byte` so you could have a timing issue. Do you debounce your keys and do you ensure that a long press of key 3 doesn't call the read function repetitively?

Comment: @MikeD Thanks for reply, I am using external 11.059000mhz quartz. I am not using debounce, and yes it is keeping repeat as long as I press it. I will try to make your suggestions to project and let you know if it works. timings issue is very probable so I will try it.